# JSP AUI Button: How to set an attribute

Tags: jsp, liferay, liferay-aui

I hope my question isnt too stupid but I just don't get it in this moment.
I found a lot of tutorials about changing pages (JSP pages) by clicking an aui button.

But I just want to set an attribute (like String abc = def;) when somebody click a button and to send it over to the processAction(..) method of my portlet.
I am using a single JSP page. The portlet class extends MVCPortlet.

So far I got:
**PortletClass**

```
    @Override
    public void processAction(ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
        String docRead = actionRequest.getParameter("docRead");
        log.info("Log says: " + docRead);
    }
```

**view.jsp**

```
<%
String docRead = "FOOBAR DO I SAY";
%>

<aui:button name="docRead" type="submit" value="I have read this" />
```

I think there is an easy solution for this like 'actionParameters.setPreferences();' or something like this but I cant find something.

I hope someone could give me a hint, iam just stucked right now.
Thanks!

Comment: It might help you [Liferay - Passing Information from the Action Phase to the Render Phase](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/passing-information-from-the-action-phase-to-the-render-phase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to provide an `onClick` event that is the `actionURL` you are trying to call.

Define the `actionURL`

```
<portlet:actionURL name='someActionMethodName' var="myURL">
  <portlet:param name="parameterLookupKey" value="Some Value You Want To Pass" />
</portlet:actionURL>
```

Implement the method in your `Action` class

```
public void someActionMethodName(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response){
    System.out.println(ParamUtil.getString(request, "parameterLookupKey"));
}
```

To call the `generic` `processAction` method you would simply replace the method name in the `actionURL` with that exact text.

```
<portlet:actionURL name='processAction' var="myURL">
  <portlet:param name="parameterLookupKey" value="Passed to Generic Process Action" />
</portlet:actionURL>
```

To use the `actionURL` with the `<aui:button>`:

```
<aui:button value="Button Text" onClick='<%=myURL.toString()%>'></aui:button>
```